# discord.py on_message is breaking bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

If I put this in main.py the bot is broken and no commands work but I don't get an error

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        embed=discord.Embed(description='My prefix here is ?. You can see available commands by typing `?help`', color=0x850000)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

---

---

---

and If put this in cogs/commands.py, `on_message` still doesn't work but other commands work. but I get this error everytime I type something into discord even without prefix

> File "C:\Users\BUGA\Documents\VSCODE\Python Projects\activity
> role\cogs\commands.py", line 17, in on_message
> if client.user.mentioned_in(message): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mentioned_in'

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        embed=discord.Embed(description='My prefix here is ?. You can see available commands by typing ?help', color=0x850000)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first piece of code, you can use `await client.process_commands(message)`. You can have a look at [the docs' Frequently Asked Questions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) for more information, but in simplicity:

> ```py
> @client.event
> async def on_message(message):
>    # do whatever you needed to do in your on_message
>    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
>        await message.channel.send("My prefix for this server is ?")
>
>    await client.process_commands(message)
> ```

Refrences:

- Discord.py docs: [Why does on_message make my commands stop working?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

Comment: that worked thanks. when I had all code in one file `main.py` the `on_message` used to work without `await client.process_commands(message)` why is that?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't use the commands extension?

Answer (score 0):

From your error, client.user is evaluating as None. From the docs, client.user returns None if the user is not logged in. So check what client.user is returning, and then see if you can get a different result with a logged in user